# install dlib using Visual Studio 2015 libraries

Tags: python, visual-studio, c++11, dlib

I've downloaded dlib and when I'm trying to install It using `python setup install` It give me this error, I'm using Visual Studio 2015 professional

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing dependency_links to dlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to dlib.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Mouhsine\Desktop\DeepLearning and SVM\dlib-master\tools\python
 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Mouhsine\Desktop\DeepLearning and SVM\dlib-master\build\l
ib.win-amd64-3.5 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=D:\Python35\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE
=C:\Users\Mouhsine\Desktop\DeepLearning and SVM\dlib-master\build\lib.win-amd64-3.5 -A x64'
-- pybind11 v2.2.2
-- Using CMake version: 3.11.0-rc4
-- NOTE: Visual Studio didn't have good enough C++11 support until Visual Studio 2015 update 3 (v19.
0.24210.0)
-- So we aren't enabling things that require full C++11 support (e.g. the deep learning tools).
-- Also, be aware that Visual Studio's version naming is confusing, in particular, there are multipl
e versions of 'update 3'
-- So if you are getting this message you need to update to the newer version of Visual Studio to us
e full C++11.
-- Enabling SSE4 instructions
-- C++11 activated.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:31 (message):
  You have to use a version of Visual Studio that supports C++11.  As of
  December 2017, the only versions that have good enough C++11 support to
  compile the dlib Pyhton API is a fully updated Visual Studio 2015 or a
  fully updated Visual Studio 2017.  Older versions of either of these
  compilers have bad C++11 support and will fail to compile the Python
  extension.  ***SO UPDATE YOUR VISUAL STUDIO TO MAKE THIS ERROR GO AWAY***
```

what should I do for my case

Comment: Did you read the error message? It tells you what to do in great detail.

Comment: What have you done to solve it?

Comment: I've tried to enable c++11 in the VS I'm using but It won't work for me

Comment: As reported on error, you need to get a new version of Visual Studio, because your version not fully support C++11. You have two option: full update 2015 or full update 2017.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,I have updated visual studio 2015 to update3, and I found version is 14.0.25431 ,not v19.0.24210.0.So I changed

```
\dlib\cmake_utils\set_compiler_specific_options.cmake file
```

, and edited

```
elseif(MSVC AND CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 19.0.24210.0 )
```

to

```
elseif(MSVC AND CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 14.0.24210.0 )
```

then everything is OK.